# Angular JS: binding a click event after angular renders HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for the first time, I have done some search but could'nt find a satisfactory answer.I am trying to fetch some data from server and binding it to page html elements on page load. But I have to also bind click event of those angular generated html elements.

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope','$timeout','service','$sce', function($scope, $timeout,service, $sce) {
 {
     $scope.results=[];
     service.getResults(function(data) {
       results=data;
      });// fetches data from server;

 }
```

I am fetching some results using an ajax call and updating the scope variable.
In my html I am using ng-repeat and binding to this array, like below

```
<div ng-controller="searchController">
   <input type="text" class="result_text" ng-repeat="result in results" value="{{result.text}}"></input>

</div>
```

Now I want to bind the click events on all elements with class result_text

Currently I am doing this using $watch and $timeout

```
$scope.$watch("results", function (value) {  

$timeout(function() {
   $(".result_text").click(function(){  //do something });
     }, 1);
 });
```

Is this the right approach. If I am not using $timeout it would run the click binding code before the html is rendered by angular.

Comment: Does this code actually populate the results? (Should `results=data;` be `$scope.results=data;`?) What are you trying to do in `//do something`?

Comment: there is `ng-click`, `ng-change` for these

Comment: @AnthonyChu yes its a typo, its $scope.results . Please note this is a theoretical question I am trying to invoke another request on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not the right approach. There are directives that do that.

replace the ugly `$(".result_text")`.click` in your contorller with:

```
data-ng-click="someFunction()"  (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)
```

in your template.

Your results can be like this:

```
service.getResults(function(data) {
    $scope.results=data;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a directive inside `ng-repeat` element that will know when `ng-repeat` has finished.

```
<div ng-controller="searchController">
  <input type="text" class="result_text" ng-repeat="result in results" value="{{result.text}}" finish-render></input>
</div>
```

Each item in `ng-repeat` has `$index` and `$last` - that is **true** when item is the last.

```
app.directive('finishRender', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        $timeout(function () {
          $(".result_text").click(function(){
            //do something
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats some useful info, I my case ng-click solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the simple on click and access functions and variables via

```
angular.element(angular_app_controller_element).scope().var/function()
```